# Sort Safari bookmarks, folders first?

Tags: bookmarks, safari

I know how to sort bookmarks in Safari (16), but is there a setting or hack to sort all the folders first, like Chrome does it?  Right now sorting mixes all the folder with the bookmarks (alphabetically), but I find it easier to have my folders at the top.

Comment: Try [these methods](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428271/how-to-sort-safari-bookmark-folders-in-macos-catalina-10-15).

Answer (score 0):

Re: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428271/how-to-sort-safari-bookmark-folders-in-macos-catalina-10-15?newreg=78539cf29662476cb71578366b634437
Re: Yair's answer (thank you for the idea) =>

Tricky(selection causes to enter renaming if not careful), but it works as follows

1. Open bookmarks panel, Create FOLDERS_SORT_TEMP on the TOP of the list
2. Press Command first, then click the BOTTOM folder to highlight it
3. release all keys, press Shift first, click to select top folder
4. Keeping cursor to the left, drag block of folders into sorting directory, proceed with sorting (right-click on temp folder, sort by name)
5. extract sorted directories out of the temp folder ABOVE it
6. Delete temp folder

Comment: This is a copy/paste of a comment!